# JavaFX focusedProperty().addListener refactor code

Tags: java, javafx, refactoring, listener

I have text fields on a form where I have I perform an action when the field is not in focus. I have a separate listener code for each field and was wondering how I can merge this code so that there is one listener code for all the fields as I have duplication of code and the only thing is different is the textfield name.

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        callPremium.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
            {
                if (newPropertyValue == false && !callPremium.getText().trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    SIMTradeCalculatorModel model = new SIMTradeCalculatorModel(numShares, purchasePrice, brokerage, callStrikePrice, putStrikePrice, putPremium, callPremium);
                    model.validateDecimal(callPremium, errorDisplay, performCalculationButton);
                    model.checkAllFields(performCalculationButton);
                }
                else {
                    callPremium.setText(callPremium.getText().trim());
                }
            }
        });

        putPremium.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
            {
                if (newPropertyValue == false && !putPremium.getText().trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    SIMTradeCalculatorModel model = new SIMTradeCalculatorModel(numShares, purchasePrice, brokerage, callStrikePrice, putStrikePrice, putPremium, callPremium);
                    model.validateDecimal(putPremium, errorDisplay, performCalculationButton);
                    model.checkAllFields(performCalculationButton);
                }
                else {
                    putPremium.setText(putPremium.getText().trim());
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what you always do with repetitive code: define a method that encapsulates the repetition and parametrize the piece that varies:

```
private ChangeListener<Boolean> createListener(TextInputControl control) {

    return (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if ((! newValue) && ( !control.getText().trim().isEmpty() )) {
            SIMTradeCalculatorModel model = new SIMTradeCalculatorModel(numShares, purchasePrice, brokerage, callStrikePrice, putStrikePrice, putPremium, control);
                model.validateDecimal(control, errorDisplay, performCalculationButton);
                model.checkAllFields(performCalculationButton);
            } else {
                control.setText(control.getText().trim());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then

```
callPremium.focusedProperty().addListener(createListener(callPremium));
putPremium.focusedProperty().addListener(createListener(putPremium));
```